# QCustomPlot example turn off layout

Tags: eclipse, qt, user-interface, layout

I have example project with QCustomPlot in QT in Eclipse. Link is http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/download. I am trying case of setupQuadraticDemo(). Example is allright, I can build and run project without problems. But QCustomPlot is anchor on left side using by layout. But I want move QCustomPlot on MainWindow by mouse movement. So I want turn off layout using. In Property Explorer I can set Layout Direction only on `LeftToRight` or `RightToLeft`. But I want cancel layout using in this project. How I can this in this example project? I am newbie in QT. Must I some edit in ui_mainwindow.h or qcustomplot.ccp or somewhere else? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I resolve this. I right click on MainWindow. Then I choose option `Lay out`. Then I clicked on `Break Layout`. Now I can displace elements on MainWindow via mouse movement.